# Pulling last entry into a summary report based on two criteria

Tags: arrays, indexing, match

I have created a report of various weeks of outcomes for our students using an Apps Script. I want to pull information from that created report into a summary report based on the last assessment rating. The data is on one tab, and the summary is on another in the same Google Sheets workbook. Here are a few things I have tried:

=ArrayFormula(IF(AND($A13='All Outcomes'!$E$4:$E$500,B$12='All Outcomes'!$B$4:$B$500),INDEX('All Outcomes'!$G$4:$G$500,MATCH(2,1/('All Outcomes'!$B$4:$B$500=B$12),1))," "))

=ArrayFormula(IF($A20='All Outcomes'!$E$4:$E$500,IFERROR(INDEX('All Outcomes'!$G$4:$G$500,MATCH(2,1/('All Outcomes'!$B$4:$B$500=B$19),1))," ")" "))

The issue seems to be that when I ask if a certain cell which references the standard on the second tab is there, I feel like it doesn't recognize it as a match.

This is a The Summary Report, which is showing multiple attempts to make it work. The first one is what should happen.